# Fragments with Collapsingtoolbarlayout and CoordinatorLAyout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have single Activity with multiple fragments. In activity I am using collapsingtoolbarlayout + Appbar (headerView + toolbar) + viewpager + fragmentholder (FrameLayout)

Each fragment which place itself into fragmentholder can have it's own collapsible headerView.

I have seen multiple example but not able to figure it out what is best practice to implement this scenario. Android documentation has nothing about this most of the example is around Activity only.

Please suggest the best practice or some documentation to refer.